# Java Abstract classes with child class

Tags: java, abstract-class

```
    abstract class Shape{
       final int b = 20;
       public void display(){
         System.out.println("This is display method");
       }
       abstract public void calculateArea();
    }

    class Rectangle extends Shape{
       public static void main(String args[]){
          Rectangle obj = new Rectangle();
          obj.display();
         //obj.b=200;
      }
    }
```

When I execute this code, it is outputting "This is display method" but in child class I create object for child class and call parent class method. Why is it invoking parent class method.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example which compiles?  I suspect you are leaving out critical code needed to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `b` is `final` in parent class. You can't change value. You will get compilation error here.
2) Method `public void calculateArea()` is absent in child class. You will get compilation error here also
3) In your code, method `void display()` isn't overrided

Comment: @llya:After fixing point 1 and 2.If display() is not overrided means what will happen ?

Comment: @ram You havn't method `display()` in `Rectangle`, so method from parent class was invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Does it compile? (Ilya is totally right)

By the way, it's calling parent method because you haven't overridden it in the child class.

```
abstract class Shape {

    [...]

    public void display() { System.out.println("Parent"); }

}

public class Rectangle extends Shape {

   [...]

    @Override
    public void display() { System.out.println("Child"); }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Rectangle().display();

    }

}
```

This outputs:

```
Child
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no wrong in o/p. shape's public method is accessible to 
rectangle
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html